# GNU Make create file from template

Tags: variables, makefile

I have a basic make experiment where I am trying to create a new file from a template with variable substitution, essentially:

```
GETCONFIG           = $(shell ./test.sh getvalue $(1) app.config.sh)
DOCKERFILE          := $(call GETCONFIG,DOCKERFILE)
DOCKERFILE_TEMP     := $(call GETCONFIG,DOCKERFILE_TEMPLATE)
DOCKERFILE_TEMPLATE := $(shell cat `./test.sh getvalue DOCKERFILE_TEMPLATE app.config.sh`)

all:
    echo $(DOCKERFILE_TEMP)
    echo $(DOCKERFILE_TEMPLATE)
    echo $(DOCKERFILE_TEMPLATE:{port}=80)
    $(file > $(DOCKERFILE),$(DOCKERFILE_TEMPLATE:{port}=80))
```

My template file is quite basic:

```
FROM node:4.3
EXPOSE {port}
```

The output of the experiment is:

```
echo Dockerfile.template
Dockerfile.template
echo  FROM node:4.3  EXPOSE {port}
FROM node:4.3 EXPOSE {port}
echo FROM node:4.3 EXPOSE 80
FROM node:4.3 EXPOSE 80
```

So, partial success, but both the last echo statement and the created file are all on one line - no line breaks from the template file. Also, you prob noticed I did not use GETCONFIG to set DOCKERFILE_TEMPLATE. Questions:

1. How do I preserve the new line char from the template file
2. How do I set DOCKERFILE_TEMPLATE using call GETCONFIG?

I also invite suggestions on "better" practices overall, but my focus of this post are the two questions above. Thank you.

Comment: Wow. While this is probably crystal clear for you, I don't think thats the case for most of the readers and that could be a reason why your question hasn't attracted any comments or answers. I'd suggest putting up an MVCE, removing all the irrelevant docker stuff, and try (over)simplifying your question.

Comment: `So, partial success, ` Why is that ? What was expected ?

Comment: Thanks for the comments kebs. This is my MVCE. Replace "docker stuff" with "some other stuff" and the MVCE is the same.

Comment: From the MVCE output you can see the template string "FROM node:4.3 EXPOSE {port}" and then see {port} is replaced as desired in the next line, "FROM node:4.3 EXPOSE 80" - the partial failure is "both the last echo statement and the created file are all on one line - no line breaks from the template file" and asked in question 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot preserve newlines with `$(shell ...)`.  It's like backticks in the shell in that respect.  The documentation is quite clear:

> The only processing make does on the result is to convert each newline
>   (or carriage-return / newline pair) to a single space. If there is a
>   trailing (carriage-return and) newline it will simply be removed.

I can't think of a way you can do this sort of processing with pure GNU make.  But you already seem to be using various shell tools, so why not use a proper shell tool to do it such as `sed`?

Comment: Thanks. So the problem is how  use make shell and then cat to read the template and not the use of make file. Im finding osx and git bash users have compatibility issues, but that could probably be addressed with careful use of sed. Before giving up on using make file - any other way to "read" the file ?

Comment: There's no way to read it in to a make variable without losing newlines currently that I'm aware of.  In the next release of GNU make it's possible the $(file ...) function will allow reading files as well as writing them.